# Finding text in Dropdown menu with Jquery and setting it to Selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to check if a particular text value exists within a `dropdown` menu and if it does I would like to set it's attribute to `selected`.

I've managed to write an `if` statement that checks to see if the text exists:

```
var country = usr.location;
if ($('select[name="country"] option:contains(' + country + ')').length) {
        $(this).find('option:contains("' + country + '")').attr('selected', 'selected');
 }
```

However, the issue I've run into is targeting the `option` and setting it to `selected`.

This is a fiddle of my work so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/javacadabra/ha2qwph3/

any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I've answered my own question but I'd be open to suggestions on ways in which my code could be improved. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this too:
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/ha2qwph3/2/)

JS:

```
var country = "Ireland";
$('select[name="country"] option').each(function(){
    if($(this).text().indexOf(country)>-1){
        $(this).attr('selected','selected');
    }
})
```

Comment: If you have contains like selector then you've no need to use each loop.

Answer (score 1):

Correct way is,

You have no scope for `this` in `if-else` condition

```
var country = "Ireland";

if($('select[name="country"] option:contains(' + country + ')').length){
     //alert('found ' + country); 
    $('select[name="country"]  option:contains(' + country + ')').attr('selected', 'selected');
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/ha2qwph3/1/)

Even a better solution to make a cache of your `select element` like,

```
var country = "Ireland";
var $countrySelected=$('select[name="country"] option:contains(' + country + ')');
if($countrySelected.length){
    //alert('found ' + country); 
    $countrySelected.attr('selected', 'selected');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I've managed to find a solution myself after tinkering with the Fiddle. Here is the Code for anyone who may need to achieve the same thing:

var country = "Ireland";

```
if($('select[name="country"] option:contains(' + country + ')').length){
     alert('found ' + country); 
    $('select[name="country"] option:contains(' + country + ')').attr('selected', 'selected');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically add a country to a variable on change and then check for the existence, fix : http://jsfiddle.net/ha2qwph3/4/

```
$('#select').change(function(){
var country = $( "select option:selected" ).html();

if($('select[name="country"] option:contains(' + country + ')').length){
     alert('found ' + country); 

}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the below code

```
$(this).find('option:contains(' + country + ')').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

with

```
$('select option:contains(' + country + ')').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Hope this helps you.Thank you.